# web3 subscriptions firing twice contract.events.MyEvent

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

**Description**

Events received from the web3 subscription are duplicated.

**Code**

```
// function used to emit an event (on smart contract)
const emitHandler = async () => {
   await contract.methods.emitEvent().send({ from: ctx.accounts[0] })
}

// having this subscription causes the subscription below to fire twice
const pickingWinnerEventSubscription = contract.events.PickingWinnerEvent({ fromBlock: 'latest' })
   .on('data', async event => {
     //     rest of code
   })

// subscription that duplicates
const winnerChosenEventSubscription = contract.events.WinnerChosenEvent({ fromBlock: 'latest' })
   .on('data', event => {
     console.log('winner was chosen!! event =>', event.returnValues)
     // rest of code
   })
```

**Tests**

When the PickingWinnerEvent subscription is commented out, the WinnerChosenEvent subscription fires once on a new event.  However, once you comment it in, the subscription suddenly fires twice.

I think I might be dealing with a bug.

Comment: Are the events always duplicated, or only sometimes?

Comment: When I clear the cookies on my browser, the events are no longer duplicated.  So only sometimes.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution? Web3js seams to fire the amount of events you subscribed too. For you tow times because you listen to tow events. Also it doesnt happen always. its a very strange behavior.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.  I agree that its a strange behavior.